# Is there a peaceful way to handle this bird slowly destroying my car?

Tags: pest-control

There is a pest of a bird doing everything it can to damage my car.

Its actions are best described by watching it in a YouTube video, though I'm not certain how or if SE allows embedding, so here is a link:

https://youtu.be/3JRmFax6oZo

It appears to want something inside of the glass or reflected in the glass, as it can be seen at the [1:52](https://youtu.be/3JRmFax6oZo?t=1m52s) point in the video to be pecking at my sunroof, but the the only thing under it is the beige cover, so the car's interior is not visible.

It also does not peck at any of the metallic parts of the car, only the glass. It is hard to catch, even on video, but I have witnessed the bird take interest in its own reflection in the mirrors.

A car cover is not an option for me as it attracts other pests, such as mice and rats, plus car covers do not last long where I am because of the very high wind gusts.

I certainly do not wish to harm the bird, and this is the only bird in over 10 years of living here that has ever done this.

If anyone knows a way I can convince the bird to leave my car alone, I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Inflatable or solar powered motorized owl?

Comment: While we do have a [tag:pest-control] tag, I'm not sure this question fits into the do-it-yourself home improvement scope of the site.

Comment: Is his pecking on the glass actually *doing anything*? If not, who cares?

Comment: @bib The pecking does very little, but the loads of bird crap all over my car do quite a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The bird is attacking his reflection in your windshield... defending his territory. I had the same problem with a car door mirror, peck marks galore. Get a car cover or put a white colored sun block behind the windshield (dark colors behind glass make mirrors... light colors don't)

Answer (score 1):

A cat would work LOL. Lots of bird problems this week. If you have a garden hose close. I use a motion activated water sprinkler. Probably will only take a few times and it wont come back. [Motion sprinkler](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004YCUT4W) it keeps the geese out of my pool.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at least someone likes your car, even if it's an insane Towhee. Did you tell him you're calling the cops? He's probably got a ground or low nest nearby, birds are nuts about territory. If you can find the nest then just relocate it. There are also Sonic Sounders or put a shiny pinwheel in the ground or hang glittery ornaments in the tree or a cat ornament or spray some Bird Repellant (Towhee's are sparrows) around the car's area & maybe a little on the tires.

Comment: I do know where the nest is as it usually flies to the car from it and back to it from the car (it's in an oak tree, although high up in the tree, due to our being on a hill, the nest is only maybe 7 feet above the driveway). How would I go about moving the nest?

Comment: Yep, that's the problem. If you can't get to the nest & you might be able to tape some broom handles together to poke, push or knock it down onto a blanket, because there's likely eggs being incubated...they're too small for any decent breakfast. You can also hose it down & destroy everything. Or, you can park on the street for a month, this is the maximum time it takes for the eggs to hatch. Then, you get the squawking for a month from the demanding babies.

Comment: I can definitely get to the nest with a ladder, no problem. I'm just not sure how best to relocate it. There are lots of trees further down the hill. Could I just set it in one of those?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much anywhere is good. Another tree or a bush or someone else's tree or bush. It doesn't need to be high, just off of the ground. Day light is best & use gloves to keep your stink off of it, so the bird can see where it's going & doesn't abandon it.

Comment: Just remember that moving a nest with little ones in it is probably not legal. Just adult birds; no problem.

Comment: Also remember, since Towhees are territorial, momma might be just a bit ticket that you're messing with her nest. Wear a heavy sweatshirt, gloves, hand protection, etc. She may come after you as you approach the nest.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried an artificial owl?

Most birds are afraid of owls since they are predators. Try putting one on a post near your car.

If all else fails a pellet rifle would take care of him but would be a little more violent.

Good luck though!

Answer (score -1):

Shoot the bird with a BB gun. Won't kill the bird, but it'll get the message after a few shots if it even comes back after the first. This worked with some pigeons I had to deal with a few years ago.

Comment: If your BB gun doesn't kill birds, you got ripped off.